# Django - create custom tag to acces variable by index in template

Tags: python, django

I have a HTML template in django. It get's two variables: list of categories (queryset, as it it returned by `.objects.all()` function on model in django) and dictionary of contestants. As a key of the dictionary, I'm using id of category, and value is list of contestats. 
I want to print name of the category and then all the contestants. Now I have this:

```
{% for category in categories_list %}
    <h1>category.category_name</h1>
    {% for contestant in contestants_dict[category.id] %}
        {{ contestant }} </br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

However, when I run it, I get error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /olympiada/contestants/
Could not parse the remainder: '[category.id]' from 'contestants_dict[category.id]'
```

What I know so far is that I can't use index in template. I thought that `{% something %}` contains pure Python, but it shoved up it's just a tag. I know that I have to create my own simple_tag, but I don't know how. I read the docs [Writing custom template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags), but there is such a little information and I wasn't able to fiqure out how to create (and mainly use in a for loop) a tag, that will take dict, key and return the value. What I tried is:
templatetags/custom_tags.py:

```
from django import template


register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag
def list_index(a, b):
    return a[b]
```

and in template:

```
{% for contestant in list_index contestants_dict category.id %}
```

But I get TemplateSyntaxError.
Could you please explain/show me how to create the tag, or is there a better way to do this?
Thanks.

//EDIT:
I managed to do it this way:

```
{% list_index contestants_list category.id as cont %}
    {% for contestant in  cont %}
```

it works, but it takes 2 lines and I need to create another variable. Is there any way to do it without it?

Comment: Use a filter instead of a tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want 2 lines like that you should be able to use a filter i think

```
@register.filter
def list_index(a, b):
    return a[b]
```

Then the usage like this

```
{% for contestant in contestants_dict|list_index:category.id %}
    {{ contestant }} </br>
{% endfor %}
```